# RequireJs module load error for cached file in Android Chrome 29.x

Tags: android, google-chrome, requirejs

I'm not sure if this is an issue w/require or Chrome (29.x) on Android (4.3 Nexus 4). I have a module that fails to load when loading a cached file. I stepped through RequireJS and noticed a few things that didn't make any sense.

From what I can gather, after a script is loaded and its contents are executed, and the define method is called.

The define method stores all modules into a global queue.

Next there is an onScriptLoad event handler that is triggered. This ultimately moves all the previously defined modules in the global queue into the appropriate "defined" collection for a given context.

Stepping through my code, it looks like the onScriptLoad fires without previously invoking the "define" method.

Also looking at the network console, i don't see my file loaded.  Typically Chrome would report that the file is loaded but it was retrieved from cache.

Anyone have similar experiences?